# Permission denied in postgres

Tags: postgresql, chmod

I missed a bit with chmod and permissions.
And now got a lot of problems with access to folders.

If I start server I see in browser:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

command

```
service --status-all
```

tells that postgres works

> [ + ]  postgresq works

Next I changed next files

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
```

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

to

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost, server_ip, *'
```

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

add

```
host    all         all         server_ip/24    trust
```

then command

```
psql -U postgres -h server_ip
```

and error

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "95.213.200.26" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The following chain of actions leads to a slightly different error

command

```
which psql
```

answer

> /usr/bin/psql

```
sudo su - postgres
```

> No directory, logging in with HOME=/

```
psql
```

> psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Which file permissions do I have to change here?

Comment: run as root `find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432` ?..

Comment: it answers     /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: in browser still same error

Comment: well, aparently it is looking for a socket dir in awrong place - try `psql -h  
/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Comment: '''psql: could not connect to server: Too many levels of symbolic links
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432/.s.PGSQL.5432" '''

Comment: ah - then probably root problem is bad `ln -s`, try `psql -h  /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` then?.. I hope this one is not a link to previous :)

Comment: how do u show your code by marker?
psql: could not connect to server: Too many levels of symbolic links
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145600/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-kusko-andrew).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is really hard. I made a great mistake with permissions 777 for `/` folder and whole system broke. So it is really easier delete server and start new project.

Answer (score 0):

Check listen addres syntax. Use:

listen_addresses = '*'

For the server to listen on both localhost and the server ip.

Comment: if you update the configuration, you should restart the database service to load the new configuration. If on debian/ubuntu: sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: hmm, not reading your problem well. You are not trying to connect on a network socket. 'psql' as user 'postgres' should work. You can try to connect using the network: 'psql -h localhost', but that doesn't explain why 'psql' without arguments doesn't work when user is postgres (sudo su postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Check that [`unix_socket_directories`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-UNIX-SOCKET-DIRECTORIES) on the server is set to the same directory (`/var/run/postgresql`) as the default socket directory that was configured when the client was compiled (this requires a server restart).

Alternatively, you can use the `--host` option of `psql` or set the `PGHOST` environment variable to tell the client to look for the socket file in `/tmp`, where the server creates it.

It looks like client and server are from different installations, otherwise the configured default should be the same for both. Or you have a bad `PGHOST` environment variable set by accident.

Comment: What exactly did you try?